# Mvvm Light ViewModel With a ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

How do any of you Mvvm Light Devotees handle the following situation.  I have several "Master" ViewModels that use their own instances of a "Child" ViewModel.  i.e.

Child ViewModel - "OrderLineItemListViewModel" a viewmodel for a list of line items in an order.

Parent ViewModel - "OrderDetailViewModel" a viewmodel for an order.
Parent VIewModel - "OrderChargeViewModel" a viewmodel for charging an order.

Both parent ViewModels need to have a list of OrderLineItems, and both could be open at the same time.  Currently, I have it set up that the parent ViewModel contains a property of type child ViewModel, and then can reference it.

```
public class ChildViewModel
{
    public ChildViewModel()
    {
       Items = new ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel>
                   {
                      new ListItemViewModel("One"),
                      new ListItemViewMOdel("Two")
                   }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel> Items {get; private set;}
}

public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        ChildViewModel = new ChildViewModel();
    }

    public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel {get; set;}
}

<Window>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding ChildViewModel.Items} />
</Window>
```

Now, I feel there should be a way to do this with the ViewModelLocator and Messaging, however I haven't figured out a clean way to do so.  I know how to use the ViewModelLocator to create non-singleton instances of ViewModels, so that's fine.  However, what I can't figure out is how to have the parent ViewModel respond to child ViewModel messages and know if the message is from "its" child ViewModel and therefore should be acted on.

Anyone have any advice on how to handle this, or should I just continue to do it the way I am?  The biggest part that has me thinking, is right now, I am selectively using the ViewModelLocator and not sure if that will ultimately be intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this total answers your question, but what I have is a nested viewmodel like yours.  I have a parent view/viewmodel that has a collection (in this case an entity framework navigation property) I want the child view/viewmodel to ineract with.  That way there can be "interaction" without messaging.

So for example, if you wanted to bind the collection from the parent to a combobox in the child view model you would do it this way (note that the parent and child views are usercontrols and in the parent view a content control is bound to the child view/viewmodel):

```
<UserControl x:Class="EmployeeListView"
            DataContext="{Binding EmployeeList_VM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
    <ContentControl Name="DetailControl" DataContext="{Binding Path=Selection, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <ComboBox Name="cbStatus" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.EmployeeStatus}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=DetailControl, Path=DataContext.employee_status}"
            SelectedValuePath="idStatus"
            SelectedValue="{Binding idStatus, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
            DisplayMemberPath="chrCode"/>
    </ContentControl>
</UserControl>
```

I tried to make it as simple as possible.  Please note the itemsource binding to the ancestor usercontrol datacontext which contains the collection (EmployeeStatus) I'm binding to.  This way your child viewmodel can interact with your parent VM collections/objects without using messaging.  Otherwise i have used messaging to target specific viewmodel if that is what you are looking for but I think the above might be more simple.

**EDIT:**
In response to your comment, I think the challenge here is you want to decouple your parent/child viewmodels, but at the same time you want to be able to tell which ones are "paired".  So IMHO the way to do this is to create some type of flag/identifier that has matching properties on the parent and child view model. I would set this property in the conrtuctor of the parent viewmodel and have a second constructor for the child viewmodel that accepts this identifier in its constructor and sets that property.  Then I would use the messenger to target the viewmodel type of the parent and pass the identifer as a parameter of the message.  Then I would register the messenger in the parent viewmodel to "listen" for messages that target its "type" and check to see if the identifier flag/parameter matches the one in the parent viewmodel.

By having two constructors for the child view model this would allow you to still use the child view model in other places and not reate a direct dependency on a property type of your parent view model, which avoids coupling them together.

I hope this makes sense.  You said you are familiar with the messenger so I didn't post an example of how to target a type and add a parameter to the message, but I can if you like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using Mvvm Light, as the title says.  Thanks for your input, I don't think we're dealing with the same situation.  I'm not trying to avoid using messaging, I'm trying to use it.  I need to figure out how to use the ViewModelLocator to create both my parent and child view models (currently it only creates the parent, then the parent creates it's child manually) and have the parent know when a message from a child is *its* child (or vice versa) so it can act accordingly.

Comment: why do you want to use the messenger?  What exactly is it accomplishing?  I have found that it is better to use the messenger as little as possible and there are often better solutions.  Sorry about the framework question, didn't read closely.

Comment: I want to use the manager so I can more completely decouple my view models from each other and more completely utilize the view model locator.

Comment: Does binding DataContext make it subscribe to the INotifyPropertyChanged of the bound property (lets say the property implements this interface)?